# Conditional MySQL Query: FROM table depending of a field

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have made a gravityform risk assessment quiz. Depending on answers, assigns respondent a profile: aggressive, balanced, conservative. I have 3 MySQL tables with names corresponding to each of those profiles.

This is a single query for 1 of the 3 tables:

```
$query= "
SELECT value1
     , value3
     , value4 
  FROM aggressive
 order 
    by num 
 LIMIT 7,8
";
```

This is the gravityform field showing “aggressive, balanced or conservative”:

$profile = slideval($_POST["input_31"]);

How do I write the MySQL query so it selects the right profile and display result in 1 single HTML page, instead of having to create 3 different HTML pages with 3 different queries?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A risk assessment quiz. Oh, fun.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile = slideval($_POST["input_31"]);
$query= "SELECT value1,value3,value4 FROM $profile order by num LIMIT 7,8";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go with union or unionall

$query = “
SELECT value1,value3,value4 , ‘aggressive’ As tablename FROM aggressive

UNION

SELECT value1,value3,value4 , ‘aggressive’ As tablename FROM balanced

UNION

SELECT value1,value3,value4 , ‘aggressive’ As tablename FROM conservative”;